# The proof of random fourier features

Tags: machine-learning

I am reading the following paper.
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/papers/07.rah.rec.nips.pdf
And I came down to the proof of Claim 1. The proof states in the 6th line of page 8 that "We have $|f(\Delta)|<\epsilon$ for all $\Delta \in M_{\Delta}$ if $|f(\Delta_i)|<\epsilon/2$ and $L_f<\epsilon/2r$ for all $i$." I have no idea why this is true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $j$ be a corresponding index of the ball that covers $\Delta$.

\begin{align}
|f(\Delta)| &\le |f(\Delta)-f(\Delta_j)|+|f(\Delta_j)|\\
&< L_f|\Delta - \Delta_j| + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&\le \left(\frac{\epsilon}{2r}\right) (r) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
& = \epsilon
\end{align}

The first inequality is due to triangle inequality and the second inequality is due to Lipschitz condition.

Comment: Why is $|\Delta-\Delta_j|\leq r$?

Comment: $\Delta_j$ is the center of a ball with radius $r$ and $\Delta$ is within the ball.